# Context.Consumer source value map not rendering any element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to **render** a series of messages that are gathered from a `Context.Consumer`.

My implementation is as follows:

```
class UserChat extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column">
        <span>test nessages</span>
        <sessionContext.Consumer>
          {(session) => {
            session.chat.lastMessages.map((message) => {
              console.log(message);
              return <span key={message.id}>{message.text}</span>;
            });
          }}
        </sessionContext.Consumer>
      </Box>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(UserChat);
```

The **issue** is that **no message** is rendered apart from the test message.

`console.log(message)` outputs the following:

```
{userName: "User1", avatar: "", id: 12355435435, text: "Test message"}
{userName: "User2", avatar: "", id: 210394240, text: "Test message 2"}
```

### React Devtools *correctly* valued:

[image]

### Element Tree Missing span elements:

[image]

Comment: I would like to add that I have tried different variations and I have probably browsed one hour and found no solution. Most likely I am missing something that I don't understand as I'm new to ReactJS concepts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to return your mapped JSX.

```
class UserChat extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Box display="flex" flexDirection="column">
        <span>test nessages</span>
        <sessionContext.Consumer>
          {(session) => {
            return session.chat.lastMessages.map((message) => {
              console.log(message);
              return <span key={message.id}>{message.text}</span>;
            });
          }}
        </sessionContext.Consumer>
      </Box>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(UserChat);
```

Comment: I feel so blind! I have literally seen the same answer on different questions, but I related them to the `return` inside `map` function itself. Cheers for pointing out "return mapped jsx".

Comment: Lol, the only reason I figure this out so quickly is because I've done it so many times myself.